# Como posso criar um layout igual á imagem com QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Estou aprendendo QML agora e quero criar algo parecido com a imagem anexada, já tentei criar alguma coisa mas não consigo manipular os botões do menu vertical e deixar igual a imagem, alguém poderia me mostrar o que devo fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 Window {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello World")

        color: "gainsboro"

        Rectangle {
            id: page
            width: 320; height: 1020
            color: "navy"

            Text {
                id: helloText
                y: 30
                anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
                font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
            }

        Button {
                text: "button"
                style: ButtonStyle {
                    background: Rectangle {
                        implicitWidth: 321
                        implicitHeight: 25
                        border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
                        border.color: "#fff"
                        radius: 0
                        gradient: Gradient {
                            GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#ccc" : "deepskyblue" }
                            GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#aaa" : "deepskyblue" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }

         Item {
                    x: 520; y: 50;
                    width: 300; height: 100

                    Row { 
                        spacing: 20 
                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                    }

                    Row { 
                        spacing: 20
                        x: 0; y: 220;

                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                        Rectangle { width: 300; height: 100; color: "white" }
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente seu problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual. Pedidos de refatoração completa, código pronto, tutoriais e/ou coisas que envolvem mais de um assunto ou procedimento no mesmo post geralmente não se encaixam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Se tem dúvida em algum detalhe específico, postar um [MCVE] da dificuldade pode ajudar bastante.

Comment: @Bacco Agora será que já podes me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Pode experimentar seguindo o exemplo em baixo...

Ex:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
   width: Screen.width
   height: Screen.height
   visible: true
   title: qsTr("Layout")

   property color leftFrame_bgcolor: "#3c4a55"
   property color main_bgcolor: "#ebebeb"

ListModel {
    id: _listModelMenu

    ListElement {
        label: "Sites"
        icon : "caminho_icon"
        fun: ()=>{console.log("Clicked on: Sites")}
    }

    ListElement {
        label: "Secure Notes"
        icon : "caminho_icon"
        fun: ()=>{console.log("Clicked on: Secure Notes")}
    }

    ListElement {
        label: "Form Files"
        icon : "caminho_icon"
        fun: ()=>{console.log("Clicked on: Form Files")}
    }

    ListElement {
        label: "Sharing Center"
        icon : "caminho_icon"
        fun: ()=>{console.log("Clicked on: Sharing Center")}
    }

    ListElement {
        label: "Security Challenge"
        icon : "caminho_icon"
        fun: ()=>{console.log("Clicked on: Security Challenge")}
    }
}

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: main_bgcolor
}

Column {
    id: leftFrame
    width: 300
    height: parent.height
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 0
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: 0

    Rectangle {
        id: backgroundColor
        color: leftFrame_bgcolor
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "transparent"
        height: 100
        width: parent.width

        Image {
            id: _icon
            source: "source_image"
            height: 25
            width: height
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 30
        }

        Text {
            id: _label
            text: "Collapse"
            font.family: "Arial"
            font.bold: true
            color: "#959595"
            font.pixelSize: 20
            anchors.left: _icon.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 25
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        id: _rpt_btns
        model: _listModelMenu
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: _btn
            color: _ma.containsMouse ? "#20313b" : "transparent"
            height: 50
            width: parent.width

            Image {
                id: _iconbtn
                source: icon
                height: 25
                width: height
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 30
            }

            Text {
                id: _labelbtn
                text: label
                font.family: "Arial"
                font.bold: true
                color:  _ma.containsMouse ? "white" : "#959595"
                font.pixelSize: 20
                anchors.left: _iconbtn.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 25
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: _ma
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {
                    fun()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

Item {
    width: parent.width - leftFrame.width
    height: parent.height
    anchors.left: leftFrame.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 0

    Rectangle {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 100
        width: parent.width - 10
        height: 2
        color: "#959595"
    }

    Grid {
        id: middleView
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 200
        columns: 2
        rows: 2

        Rectangle {
            color: "white"
            width: 400
            height: 200
            border.color: "#959595"
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "white"
            width: 400
            height: 200
            border.color: "#959595"
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "white"
            width: 400
            height: 200
            border.color: "#959595"
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "white"
            width: 400
            height: 200
            border.color: "#959595"
        }
    }

}
```

}